# read data from a specific partition of a dataset in spark java

Tags: parallel-processing, spark-java

I want to read data from each partition in a dataset spark java

```
 loadedCompanyModelDf.foreachPartition(p -> {
      Iterable<Row> rowIt = () -> p;
      List<Row> objs = StreamSupport.stream(rowIt.spliterator(), true)
                            .filter(row -> row.size() > 0)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

 });
```

where loadedCompanyModelDf is the Dataset. 
I want to access the data in each partition as a Dataset. How do I convert List to Dataset
Can anyone provide any inputs for this.?

Comment: Question is ambiguous: do you want to read from a "specific partition" (i.e. just one, that is chosen arbitrarily) or from "each partition" (i.e. all of them, possibly in parallel)?

Comment: from each partition, yes in parallel. Updating my question.